# Delphi and Indy TIdFTP: Copy all files from one folder on the server to another

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm using `TIdFTP` (Indy 10.6) for a client application and I need to be able to copy all files from one folder on the server to another. Can this be done?

I know how to rename or move a file, we can use `TIdFTP.Rename(Src, Dst)`.
How about the copy? Would I need to use `Get()` and `Put()` with a new path / name, knowing that the number of files in the server can exceed 500,000 files.

In our company, we have some files whose size exceeds 1.5 GB. By using my code, it consumes a lot of memory and the file is not copied from one directory to another: in less code, the source directory is named "Fichiers" and the destination directory is named "Sauvegardes".

Here is my code:

```
var
  S , directory  : String;
  I: Integer;
  FichierFTP : TMemoryStream;
begin

  IdFTP1.Passive := True;

  idftp1.ChangeDir('/Fichiers/'); 
  IdFTP1.List();

  if IdFTP1.DirectoryListing.Count > 0 then begin

    IdFTP1.List();

    for I := 0 to IdFTP1.DirectoryListing.Count-1 do begin

      with IdFTP1.DirectoryListing.Items[I] do begin

        if ItemType = ditFile then begin

          FichierFTP := TMemoryStream.Create;

          S := FileName;

          idftp1.Get( FileName , FichierFTP , false );

          Application.ProcessMessages
          idftp1.ChangeDir('/Sauvegardes/' ); 
          idftp1.Put(FichierFTP , S );

          Application.ProcessMessages;
          FichierFTP.Free;  
        end;
      end;
    end;
    IdFTP1.Disconnect;
  end;
```

Does anyone have any experience with this?  How can I change my code to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no provisions in the FTP protocol, and thus no methods in `TIdFTP`, to copy/move *multiple* files at a time. Only to copy/move *individual* files one at a time.

*Moving* a file from one FTP folder to another is easy, that can be done with the `TIdFTP.Rename()` method.  However, *copying* a file typically requires issuing separate commands to download the file locally first and then re-upload it to the new path.

Some FTP servers support custom commands for *copying* files, so that you do not need to download/upload them locally.  For example, ProFTPD's `mod_copy` module implements [`SITE CPFR/CPTO`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_copy.html) commands for this purpose.  If your FTP server supports such commands, you can use the `TIdFTP.Site()` method, eg:

```pascal
Item := IdFTP1.DirectoryListing[I];
if Item.ItemType = ditFile then
begin
  try
    IdFTP1.Site('CPFR ' + Item.FileName);
    IdFTP1.Site('CPTO /Sauvegardes/' + Item.FileName);
  except
    // fallback to another transfer option, see further below...
  end;
end;
```

If that does not work, another possibility to avoid having to copy each file locally is to use a site-to-site transfer between 2 separate `TIdFTP` connections to the same FTP server.  If the server allows this, you can use the `TIdFTP.SiteToSiteUpload()` and `TIdFTP.SiteToSiteDownload()` methods to make the server transfer files to itself, eg:

```pascal
IdFTP2.Connect;
...
Item := IdFTP1.DirectoryListing[I];
if Item.ItemType = ditFile then
begin
  try
    IdFTP1.SiteToSiteUpload(IdFTP2, Item.FileName, '/Sauvegardes/' + Item.FileName);
  except
    try
      IdFTP2.SiteToSiteDownload(IdFTP1, Item.FileName, '/Sauvegardes/' + Item.FileName);
    except
      // fallback to another transfer option, see further below...
    end;
  end;
end;
...
IdFTP2.Disconnect;
```

But, if using such commands is simply not an option, then you will have to resort to downloading each file locally and then re-uploading it.  When *copying* a large file in this manner, you should use `TFileStream` (or similar) instead of `TMemoryStream`.  Do not store large files in memory.  Not only do you risk a memory error if the memory manager can't allocate enough memory to hold the entire file, but once that memory has been allocated and freed, the memory manager will hold on to it for later reuse, it does not get returned back to the OS.  This is why you end up with such high memory usage when you transfer large files, even after all transfers are finished.

If you really want to use a `TMemoryStream`, use it for smaller files only. You can check each file's size on the server (either via `TIdFTPListItem.Size` if available, otherwise via `TIdFTP.Size()`) before downloading the file, and then choose an appropriate `TStream`-derived class to use for that transfer, eg:

```pascal
const
  MaxMemoryFileSize: Int64 = ...; // for you to choose...
var
  ...
  FichierFTP : TStream;
  LocalFileName: string;
  RemoteFileSize: Int64;

Item := IdFTP1.DirectoryListing[I];
if Item.ItemType = ditFile then
begin
  LocalFileName := '';
  if Item.SizeAvail then
    RemoteFileSize := Item.Size
  else
    RemoteFileSize := IdFTP1.Size(Item.FileName);
  if (RemoteFileSize >= 0) and (RemoteFileSize <= MaxMemoryFileSize) then
  begin
    FichierFTP := TMemoryStream.Create;
  end else
  begin
    LocalFileName := MakeTempFilename;
    FichierFTP := TFileStream.Create(LocalFileName, fmCreate);
  end;
  try
    IdFTP1.Get(Item.FileName, FichierFTP, false);
    IdFTP1.Put(FichierFTP, '/Sauvegardes/' + Item.FileName, False, 0);
  finally
    FichierFTP.Free;
    if LocalFileName <> '' then
      DeleteFile(LocalFileName);
  end;
end;
```

There are other optimizations you can make to this, for instance creating a single `TMemoryStream` with a pre-sized `Capacity` and then reuse it for multiple transfers that will not exceed that `Capacity`.

---

So, putting this all together, you could end up with something like the following:

```pascal
var
  I: Integer;
  Item: TIdFTPListItem;
  SourceFile, DestFile: string;
  IdFTP2: TIdFTP;
  CanAttemptRemoteCopy: Boolean;
  CanAttemptSiteToSite: Boolean;

  function CopyFileRemotely: Boolean;
  begin
    Result := False;
    if CanAttemptRemoteCopy then
    begin
      try
        IdFTP1.Site('CPFR ' + SourceFile);
        IdFTP1.Site('CPTO ' + DestFile);
      except
        CanAttemptRemoteCopy := False;
        Exit;
      end;
      Result := True;
    end;
  end;

  function CopyFileSiteToSite: Boolean;
  begin
    Result := False;
    if CanAttemptSiteToSite then
    begin
      try
        if IdFTP2 = nil then
        begin
          IdFTP2 := TIdFTP.Create(nil);
          IdFTP.Host := IdFTP1.Host;
          IdFTP.Port := IdFTP1.Port;
          IdFTP.UserName := IdFTP1.UserName;
          IdFTP.Password := IdFTP1.Password;
          // copy other properties as needed...
          IdFTP2.Connect;
        end;
        try
          IdFTP1.SiteToSiteUpload(IdFTP2, SourceFile, DestFile);
        except
          IdFTP2.SiteToSiteDownload(IdFTP1, SourceFile, DestFile);
        end;
      except
        CanAttemptSiteToSite := False;
        Exit;
      end;
      Result := True;
    end;
  end;

  function CopyFileManually: Boolean;
  const
    MaxMemoryFileSize: Int64 = ...;
  var
    FichierFTP: TStream;
    LocalFileName: String;
    RemoteFileSize: Int64;
  begin
    Result := False;
    try
      if Item.SizeAvail then
        RemoteFileSize := Item.Size
      else
        RemoteFileSize := IdFTP1.Size(SourceFile);
      if (RemoteFileSize >= 0) and (RemoteFileSize <= MaxMemoryFileSize) then
      begin
        LocalFileName := '';
        FichierFTP := TMemoryStream.Create;
      end else
      begin
        LocalFileName := MakeTempFilename;
        FichierFTP := TFileStream.Create(LocalFileName, fmCreate);
      end;
      try
        IdFTP1.Get(SourceFile, FichierFTP, false);
        IdFTP1.Put(FichierFTP, DestFile, False, 0);
      finally
        FichierFTP.Free;
        if LocalFileName <> '' then
          DeleteFile(LocalFileName);
      end;
    except
      Exit;
    end;
    Result := True;
  end;

begin
  CanAttemptRemoteCopy := True;
  CanAttemptSiteToSite := True;

  IdFTP2 := nil;
  try
    IdFTP1.Passive := True;

    IdFTP1.ChangeDir('/Fichiers/'); 
    IdFTP1.List;

    for I := 0 to IdFTP1.DirectoryListing.Count-1 do
    begin
      Item := IdFTP1.DirectoryListing[I];

      if Item.ItemType = ditFile then
      begin
        SourceFile := Item.FileName;
        DestFile := '/Sauvegardes/' + Item.FileName;

        if CopyFileRemotely then
          Continue;

        if CopyFileSiteToSite then
          Continue;

        if CopyFileManually then
          Continue;

        // failed to copy file! Do something...
      end;
    end;
  finally
    IdFTP2.Free;
  end;

  IdFTP1.Disconnect;
end;
```

Comment: Remy: thank you so much for your help and for your time.
Our server does not allow the first two options: "**CopyFileRemotely**" and "**CopyFileSiteToSite**" .        
  I tried the "**CopyFileManually**" function with:
(**MaxMemoryFileSize: Int64 = 50000**) but I get an error message:
"The Project1.exe project raised the EFCreateError exception class with the message 'Unable to create file The syntax of the file, directory or volume name is incorrect'."

Comment: Did you try debugging the code to find out why it is failing? Sounds like maybe `MakeTempFilename()` is not returning a valid file path, so `TFileStream.Create()` then fails. Use whatever mechanism you want to generate a local file path for your purposes.

Comment: I debugged the code and you're right, "MakeTempFilename" is the problem.it does not return the valid path.  what do you mean please by :
"_Use the mechanism you want to generate a local file path for your purposes_".

Comment: What exactly does `MakeTempFilename()` return for you?  Is it returning a blank string, or an improperly constructed string? Please be more specific. As for the other comment, I just mean that you can use whatever you want to build up a path+filename string that suils your needs. Use a hard-coded path, use a hard-coded fileame with a path queried from the OS, use an OS-queried path with a random generated filename (which is what `MakeTempFilename()` does), etc. The point is to create a valid string that holds a path+filename can be used to create a physical file on your local machine.

Comment: it works perfectly !!! the problem was:  a hard-coded fileame + a path. I added them and it works !! I want to thank you Remy for your precious help and your time. Thanks again and it's so nice from you to share this code.

Comment: Glad it is working now, but you didn't answer my question about `MakeTempFilename()`, what is the actual problem using it?

Comment: MakeTempFilename() : returning a blank string. Since I did not add the temporary file path, this generates a compiler error. But when I added the a hard-coded fileame + a path, the error disappeared and everything works fine

Comment: "*MakeTempFilename() : returning a blank string*" - hmm, it should not be doing that. Can you [file a bug report](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues) for me? And be sure to include an example, and info about the platform(s) it is failing on. Thanks.

Comment: it is not a bug. My application directory was in the root of the disk: "C: \ File backups" and Windows has not granted the privilege to create a new file (temp file in this directory). I just noticed when I moved the directory of my application to another partition of the disk and there, it did not have this problem. So no IdFtp bug.

Comment: "*My application directory was in the root of the disk: "C:\File backups" and Windows has not granted the privilege to create a new file*" - You said that `MakeTempFilename()` is returning a blank string, which should never happen. If you leave the optional `APath` parameter blank, it should return a filename in the system `%TEMP%` folder. So, the only way it could return a path to your drive root is if that is where `%TEMP%` is, or if you pass that folder in the `APath` param.

Comment: "*I just noticed when I moved the directory of my application to another partition of the disk and there, it did not have this problem.*" - this kind of behavior can only happen if `MakeTempFilename()` returns a blank string, which you then append a filename to. `MakeTempFilename()` is supposed to return a full path+filename to you, you should not be appending anything to its output.

Comment: "*So no IdFtp bug*" - I never said this was a `TIdFTP` bug. But you make it sound like there is a bug in `MakeTempFilename()` that needs to be investigated.